# Trying to create a new column based on multiple conditions in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to create new column based on multiple conditions on multiple column and I keep getting the following error

```
Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

The code that I have written is as below :

```
condition = [frame['Type'] == 'Commercial' & frame['var'].str.contains("IN-MARKET", case=False) 
& pd.DatetimeIndex(frame['Day']).year == 2019 & pd.DatetimeIndex(frame['Day']).month == 2,
frame['Type'] == 'Commercial' & frame['Campaign'].str.contains("FruitnNuts", case=False) & 
frame['var'].str.contains("300X250", case=False) & frame['Day'] >= '2019-04-08' & frame['Day'] <= '2019-04-20']
    
frame['norm'] = np.select(condition, [frame['imp']*0.03, imp*0.01], 
                                         default=frame['completes'])
```

I am hoping if someone can please help to resolve the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please provide a minimal dataframe and desired output

Comment: Please see the following link on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples